# Python Selenium. How to use driver.set_page_load_timeout() properly?

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(7)

def urlOpen(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print driver.current_url
    except:
        return
```

Then I have URL lists and call above methods.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    urls = ['http://motahari.ir/', 'http://facebook.com', 'http://google.com']
    # It doesn't print anything

    # urls = ['http://facebook.com', 'http://google.com', 'http://motahari.ir/'] 
    # This prints https://www.facebook.com/ https://www.google.co.kr/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=3bfdWdzWAYvR8geelrqQAw&gws_rd=ssl

    for url in urls:
        urlOpen(url)
```

The problem is when website 'http://motahari.ir/' throws Timeout Exception, websites 'http://facebook.com' and 'http://google.com' always throw Timeout Exception.

Browser keeps waiting for 'motahari.ir/' to load. But the loop just goes on (It doesn't open 'facebook.com' but wait for 'motahari.ir/') and keep throwing timeout exception

Initializing a webdriver instance takes long, so I pulled that out of the method and I think that caused the problem. Then, should I always reinitialize webdriver instance whenever there's a timeout exception? And How? (Since I initialized driver outside of the function, I can't reinitialize it in except)

Comment: Why are you trying to load a webpage in under 5 seconds....that’ll be difficult...

Comment: I don’t think it should happen though. Everything seems correct, (other than the fact that you hadn’t import `By` yet) it might be just because your internet is slow or the website’s server is slow...

Comment: *"But the loop just goes on (It doesn't open 'b.net' but wait for 'a.com') and keep throwing timeout exception"* It doesn't, it actually is loading b.net, it just doesn't show it on the top. And I'll like you to know that links in selenium requires a prefix "https://" or "http://" to work.

Comment: Sorry, I had a method to add http but I omitted that for simplicity. I changed the code a little bit. Could you have a look at it, please?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will just need to clear the browser's cookies before continuing. (Sorry, I missed seeing this in your previous code)

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(7)

def urlOpen(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print(driver.current_url)
    except:
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        print("Failed")
        return

urls = ['http://motahari.ir/', 'https://facebook.com', 'https://google.com']

for url in urls:
    urlOpen(url)
```

Output:

```
Failed
https://www.facebook.com/
https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=o73dWfnsO-vs8wfc5pZI
```

P.S. It is not very wise to do `try...except...` without a clear Exception type, is this might mask different unexpected errors.

Comment: Sometimes it throws another timeout exception while deleting cookies... any idea?

Comment: No sorry, it never raised any errors on mine, so I don’t know why it happened on yours D:

Comment: when I set set_page_load_timeout() and later call delete_all_cookies() I get a timeout exception. Why would delete_all_cookies() be throwing a timeout exception?