# Why does delete_all_cookies() sometimes throw a timeoutException?

Tags: python, selenium, cookies

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(7)

def urlOpen(url):
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        print(driver.current_url)
    except:
        driver.delete_all_cookies()
        print("Failed")
        return

urls = ['http://motahari.ir/', 'https://facebook.com', 'https://google.com']

for url in urls:
    urlOpen(url)
```

Actually, this question was [Python Selenium. How to use driver.set_page_load_timeout() properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680312/python-selenium-how-to-use-driver-set-page-load-timeout-properly).

The modified code above works just fine usually, but strangely, about 2 out of 10 times `delete_all_cookies()` throws `timeoutException`. I tried adding another `try-catch` block, implicit/explicit wait, or `time.sleep` before `delete_all_cookies()` but all didn't work.

I have no idea why and how `delete_all_cookies()` throws `timeoutException`... Is there any way to prevent that?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/urlOpen.py", line 19, in <module>
urlOpen(url)
  File "C:/urlOpen.py", line 12, in urlOpen
driver.delete_all_cookies()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 692, in delete_all_cookies
self.execute(Command.DELETE_ALL_COOKIES)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: timeout
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Sometimes, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/urlOpen.py", line 18, in <module>
urlOpen(url)
  File "C:/urlOpen.py", line 11, in urlOpen
driver.delete_all_cookies()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 692, in delete_all_cookies
self.execute(Command.DELETE_ALL_COOKIES)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Comment: strange issue, can u please paste the exception log

Comment: Had you find what was the cause? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: 2 years later, I am also experiencing this.  I am catching the exception and moving on, but I would like it to actually delete the cookies.